# Media Queries not overriding native styles?

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive-design

I'm wondering why some of my media queries are not overriding the native styles at the view port their being called. I'm trying to restyle a menu responsively, to stack, and have the navigation area's height longer in a WP theme. But every which way I add the specs I create to get this effect via editing Live CSS in Safari or FF inspect element - the styles I insert under the specific viewport I'm targeting are not being read. I know I'm using media queries correctly as it reads NEW styles, just doesn't override native? I'm missing something here? Here's what I'm trying to add that won't read.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {

#access li {
    float: none; // To translate to not to float to the left stack
    position: relative;
}

#access {
    background: url("http://testsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/menu_bg.gif") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 240px; //Changed the height to allow stack
    width: 100%;
}
```

Edit: **Here's the *FULL* set of Responsive styles I'm calling, if matters.**

```
  /* =Responsive Structure
----------------------------------------------- */

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    body {
        padding: 0;
    }
    #page {
        margin-top: 0; overflow: hidden;
    }
    #branding {
        border-top: none;
    }
        #signup { display:none; }
        #adbox { display:none; }
        #adbox2 { display:none; }
        #socialpost { margin-left: -100px; }
        p {font-size: 12px; }
        #sublogo { display: none; }
        #footcontain {  padding-left: 0;}

        #access a {
        color: #000000;
        display: block;
        font-family: arial;
        line-height: 3.11em;
        padding: 0 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        #access a { font-size: 12px; }

        #access li {
        float: left;
        margin-left: -28px;
        position: relative; }
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
    /* @media (max-width: 650px) Reduce font-sizes for better readability on smaller devices */
    body {
        padding: 0;
    }
    #page {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    #branding {
        border-top: none;
    }
        #signup { display:none; }
        #adbox { display:none; }
        #adbox2 { display:none; }
        p {font-size: 12px; }
        #sublogo { display: none; }

        #access a {
         color: #000000;
         display: block;
         font-family: arial;
         line-height: 3.11em;
         padding: 0 13px;
         text-decoration: none;
         font-size: 11px;}
         #footcontain {  padding-left: 0;}
         #access a {
         padding: 0 15px; }

}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
        #content .gallery-columns-2 .gallery-item {
    width: 45%;
    padding-right: 4%;
    }
    #content .gallery-columns-2 .gallery-item img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
        #signup { display:none; }
        #adbox { display:none; }
        #adbox2 { display:none; }
        p {font-size: 10px; }

       .entry-content, .entry-summary {
        padding: 1.625em 0 0;
        width: 48%; }
        #footcontain {  padding-left: 0;}

        #branding #s {
       -moz-transition-duration: 400ms;
       -moz-transition-property: width, background;
       -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
        float: right;
        height: 35px;
        width: 47px; }

        .widget-title { margin-top: 35px; }

        .flexslider .slides img {
         border: 0 none;
         display: block;
         max-width: 100%;
         padding-bottom: 25px; }
         #footcontain {  display:none;}

         #access li {
         float: none;
         position: relative;
         }

         #access {
         height: 70px;
         }

         #access a {
         color: #000000;
         display: block;
         font-family: arial;
         font-weight: bolder;
         line-height: 3.11em;
         padding: 0 10px;
         text-decoration: none;
         }

         #access ul {
         font-size: 10px;
         list-style: none outside none;
         margin: 0 0 0 -80px;
         padding-left: 0;
         }

        .flex-control-nav { display: none; }
        .flexslider {
         margin: 0 0 67px; }
        .flex-caption {  display: none; } //Could Display this here, need to make take half of slider

}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    body { padding: 0; }

        #access {
        height: 70px;
        }

    #page {
        margin-top: 0; overflow: hidden;
    }
    #branding {
        border-top: none;
    }
        #signup { display:none; }
        #adbox { display:none; }
        #adbox2 { display:none; }
        p {font-size: 10px; }
        #sublogo { display: none; }
        #access a { padding: 0 10px; }

        #access li {
        float: none;
        position: relative;
        }

       .entry-content, .entry-summary {
        padding: 1.625em 0 0;
        width: 35%; }
        #footcontain {  display: none; }

       #branding #s {
         -moz-transition-duration: 400ms;
         -moz-transition-property: width, background;
         -moz-transition-timing-function: ease;
         float: right;
         height: 35px;
         width: 47px; }

        #footcontain { display: none; }

        .widget-title { margin-top: 35px; } //Attempt to Create Space for Slider Page Nation
        #access { height: 70px; }

        #access li {
        float: none;
        position: relative;
        }

       .flex-control-nav { display: none; }

       .flex-caption {  display: none; } //Could Display this here, need to make take half of slider, check 
       .flexslider {
       margin: 0 0 67px; }

}
```

Comment: You are saying that it doesn't work, but have you actually tested that on a device? You've only mentioned that it doesn't overwrite the styles in Chrome or Firefox - in general I think 'min-device-width' only works on a device and not in "desktop browser".

Comment: Great point. But I've tested using 'Safari Resizer' - which I was told was identical to iPad at correct resolutions. And also used popular emulators like iPadpeek. Those should be somewhat accurate right?

Comment: I think that `Safari Resizer` only affects the browser resolution and allows you to create `custom presets` and does not change how `Media Queries` are interpreted, please check my answer

Comment: I will try to see if it renders on the actual devices as soon as I can, and keep the question updated. BUT, I'm confused as some Media Queries do show with window resize.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `CSS` code from your post is not working because it's a device-specific style and you are viewing it on a Safari, Chrome or Firefox using a laptop/desktop. You are forgetting that `Media Queries` are giving you the possibility to apply different styles when a page is being displayed in a 'browser' - resized to 480px and on an iPhone (which has a max-device-width of 480px).

**Example CSS:**

```
/* max-width */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .one {
        background: #F9C;
    }
}

/* min-width & max-width */
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 900px) {
    .two {
        background: #9CF;
    }
}

/* min-width */
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .three {
        background: #F90;
    }
}

/* iphone specific css */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    .iphone {
        background: #ccc;
    }
}
```

In the example above you can target both and still have a separate style for your device of choice. If you want to test it in a `browser` just use the `min-width` or `max-width` properties.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

On the top example there's a missing *closing bracket*.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {

  #access li {
    float: none; // To translate to not to float to the left stack
    position: relative;
  }

  #access {
    background: url("http://testsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/menu_bg.gif") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 240px; //Changed the height to allow stack
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I originally thought too. That was just how I pasted it in SO though. I've edited the question including all of my media querie styles now - and doesn't seem I've missed a bracket.